# Where should I put media files for my Django-CMS plugin?

Tags: django-cms

I'm about to write `setup.py` for my Django CMS plugin, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to put the icon.

It seemed to me like the following would've been the most intuitive, judging by where you are supposed to place templates:

```
/media
  /cms
    /images
      /plugins
        my_image.png
cms_plugin.py
```

In `cms_plugin.py` I have the following method:

```
def icon_src(self, instance):
    print settings.CMS_MEDIA_URL
    return settings.CMS_MEDIA_URL + u"images/plugins/my_image.png"
```

The above works if I instead re-use the `link.png` image, but I'm looking for something I can bundle in the same folder as my plugin.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly. How many images do you have? you could stor some of the path in an attribute if that makes it easier?

Comment: I'm asking where I should put the icon according to convention, so the path returned by icon_src method will point to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a convention or not but i've noticed a few put it in

```
myproject/media/myproject/images
```

or some such equivalent.

some examples from django-cms [extensions and plugins](https://www.django-cms.org/en/extensions/)

[Zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/tree/master/zinnia/media/zinnia/img)

```
https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/tree/master/zinnia/media/zinnia/img
```

[jplayer](https://github.com/ojii/django-cms-jplayer/tree/master/jplayer/media/jplayer)

```
https://github.com/ojii/django-cms-jplayer/tree/master/jplayer/media/jplayer
```